# Problem about Conservative Vector

Tags: calculus

Let $F:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ where $F(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$. show that $F$ is a conservative vector fields, that is, there is a potential function $f$ where $\nabla f = F$ .

Comment: $F$ is the identity?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=\frac{1}{2}(x_1^2+x_2^2+\ldots+x_n^2)$

Comment: Can you show that F is a conservative vector field

Comment: Yes i know how to compute

Comment: I'll just get the partial derivative of f

Comment: Do you know what is the esplicitly potential function of that problem?